# Multiple resource folder syncing issue. #Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I'm working on a solutioning where managing multiple res folder to keep resource requirement separate and it worked great. To implement this I'm following well written **[document](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-project-structure-alternative-way-29ce766682f0)** by Dmytro Danylyk.

In my case I have two different res folder with layout directory `res/layout` and `res-home/layout`.

**Now issue is: ** if I modified layout under `res-home/layout` it's not reflecting any changes even static text string update for TextView. It required clean and build every time.

Following code using to add resource availability from gradle file:

> res.srcDirs +=
>                       [
>                               file("src/main/res_prefer/").listFiles(),
>                               'src/main/res_prefer'
>                       ]
>           }

Any clue what I'm missing !!

[image]